# Convert string to number

Tags: macros, strings

How can I convert numbers given as strings to "real" numbers? Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tag}{\StrBefore{01.01.2000}{.}}
%\setdatenumber{2000}{10}{\tag}
\setdatenumber{2000}{10}{10}
\tag \\
\datedate
\end{document}
```

Here, `\tag` is set to `01` as can be seen in the output. But if I use the line `\setdatenumber{2000}{10}{\tag}` I get the error "missing number, treated as zero". How can I avoid this? None of the other "Convert string to number" I found questions seem to be of help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by `\StrBefore` not being expandable, so the number is printed but it can not be used for further calculations. The `xstring` author added a optional argument to `\StrBefore` to help with this kind of problems: You can pass the name of a control sequence in `[]` to set this control sequence to the result of `\StrBefore`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrBefore{01.01.2000}{.}[\tag]
\setdatenumber{2000}{10}{\tag}
\tag \\
\datedate
\end{document}
```